# How to fix these two errors that pop up before Ubuntu boots?

Tags: boot, grub2, password

```
Error: can't find command 'hwmatch'.

Error: invalid PBKDF2 password.

Enter username:
Root(E.g)

Enter password:
Toor

Error: access denied 
Failed to boot both default and fallback entries

Press any key to continue..
```

The above message is what I get **before** the boot and after pressing any key the OS doesn't boot but rather it sends me to the Grub menu where I can't select absolutely anything without it continuously asking for my username and password, even after entering it's back to the Grub menu.I can't even open the minimal bash nor edit.

I think it happened after a Lynis audit asked me to add a password for something I remember now to increase security but I forgot to update grub after setting that password.

Note:all I have access to is my BIOs.

Comment: I didn't get the point . You say " add a password or something" but what ? Why did you need to update your grub ? Please clarify your question and add more useful information by pressing the [edit](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1244648/how-to-fix-these-two-errors-that-pop-up-before-ubuntu-boots#) button.

Comment: I can't find exact Ubuntu instructions but this is how to turn off grub password in other Linux systems: https://www.computernetworkingnotes.com/rhce-study-guide/how-to-reset-grub-password-in-linux.html

Comment: To start with, which Linux distro have you installed (Ubuntu server, Ubuntu desktop, Kubuntu, Lubuntu, Xubuntu, Ubuntu MATE, Mint, et al.), & which release number?  Different releases have different tools for us to recommend. Please click [edit] & add that to your question, so all facts we need are in the question. Please don't use Add Comment, since that's our one-way channel to you. All facts about your PC should go in the Question with [edit] as this is a Q&A site, not a general forum, so things work differently here.

Answer (score 0):

```
Insert or connect the Ubuntu live media (DVD or USB)
Reboot the computer from live media and choose Try Ubuntu                                  Connect to the internet, then open a terminal with Ctrl+Alt+t, paste the following   commands and run them by pressing Enter:

sudo add-apt-repository -y ppa:yannubuntu/boot-repair
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install -y boot-repair && boot-repair

The Boot-Repair window will appear 
Press Recommanded repair


Good luck!
```

Comment: When I said  "add a password or something" I meant that Lynis suggested that I add a password for grub or something that was not completely secure that I can't recall now so that if an intruder wanted to configure it they'll need a password.After reading this suggestion I searched on how to properly do it and the last step was to update grub.Which I forgot.

Comment: I use 18.04 by the way.